# Wordpress Child-Theme CSS not Reflecting on Site

Tags: css, wordpress

I've semi-successfully created a wordpress child-theme. By successfully I mean:

1. I managed to create a child-theme directory in my themes folder, next
   to my main theme
2. I created a style.css file in the child-theme dir
3. I saw the style show up on my Wordpress back-end and managed to activate it
4. I added templates (header.php, sidebar.php,...) to the directory
5. I made changes to the above templates and saw the changes on my site

However, there is one huge problem:

1. Whatever CSS I try to add to the style.css file, it's not affecting the site

I know the "information header" must be ok since I was able to see/activate the child-theme. But I really can't figure out what is wrong. I tried removing the @import rule, which according to the Wordpress codex should remove all styles from my site - nothing happened.

I'm using the Panorama theme and created "panorama-technology" as a child. Below you can see the code I have in the style.css file inside the child-theme: "panorama-technology":

```
/*
Theme Name: panorama-technology
Template: panorama
*/

@import url("../panorama/style.css");

#search{
margin: 15px 15px 0 0;
}
```

Comment: WP codex says: **Template. (required) directory name of parent theme, case-sensitive. Attention: You have to switch to a different theme and back to the child theme when you modify this line. ** Maybe that is your problem?

Comment: http://tech-papers.org/how-to-create-wordpress-child-theme/

Comment: @IvanIvanić: stupidly, this solves everything. And stupidly, the note you mention is now sadly removed from the official documentation. Yours should be added as answer and marked as correct to save head-scratching :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I'd try an absolute path to be sure that the path isn't the problem. If that does not solve the issue. Place the @import at the very top of the css file or directly after thelast "*/". I think white space is probably the culprit here.

Comment: The problem is that it's not just the @import, it's every line of CSS that is refusing to work. I tried the absolute path before, that didn't solve it either.

Comment: Can you provide a link or the css rules for #search from any of the other stylesheet that is included on the page you are testing? Your rules might be overwritten by rules in the other stylesheet(s).

Comment: http://demo.themocracy.com/panorama/wp-content/themes/panorama/style.css

#search{
background: #555;
border: 1px solid #b3b3b3;
float: right;
height: 22px;
margin: 30px 15px 0 0;
padding: 0 5px 0 0;
width:234px;
-moz-border-radius: 4px;
-khtml-border-radius: 4px;
-webkit-border-radius: 4px;
border-radius: 4px;
}

* html #search{
margin-right: 8px;
}

#search input{
background: transparent;
border: 0;
float: left;
font-size: 105%;
margin: 2px 0 0;
padding: 1px 2px 2px 10px;
width:198px;
}
#search .searchsubmit{
margin: 3px 0 0 5px;
padding: 0;
width: auto;
}

#footer a{
font-weight: 100;

Comment: The style.css file is added to the head of the document before dargrey.css is added. So the document is taking the styles for #search from the last stylesheet it reads (darkgrey.css). If you can, reverse the order they are added.  Or if that isn't possible, add a class to the body (<body class="panorama">) Then reference styles like this: .panorama #search{property:value}

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work either. When checking the source of my page, I can only see two css files:
/wp-content/themes/panorama/style.css"

Comment: and /wp-content/themes/panorama/lightgrey.css
Adding a class to the body and referencing to .panorama #search didn't work either. Neither did adding lightgrey to my child-theme and adapting it. The problem really is that the CSS files in my child theme aren't used. But I have no clue as to why this is.

Comment: I found the problem, but not the solution! In the header file, you can find the following: <?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>. I echo'd it out, to check it and it showed me the following: http://domain.be/subdir/wp-content/themes/panorama
This can only mean that for some reason it's not accepting the child theme. Since I am using a customized header, I could easily change this to reflect the child theme. But I'd rather find the real problem. Any ideas out there with this new info?

Comment: FIXED! Changed the header from <?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?> to <?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>
Now, do I get credit for this, or what?

Answer (score 10):

WouterB, I had the same problem with my child theme loading in the backend, and child php pages overriding the parent theme php pages, but NO child CSS changes loading to override the parent styles.

So,although with different coding, it turns out my parent theme was written in such a way that the header was also looking for the stylesheet in the template directory, so your solution was spot on in concept.

Thus, by changing the call in the header from :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
  href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/style.css" />
```

to:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
  href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri();?>/style.css" />
```

--did the trick like magic. At least as far as I can tell so far.

You get major credit in my book!

Comment: Haha, I think you've just revived my first post ever here. Don't think I quite knew how it all worked back then. Happy it has helped you though. Here's some power to you +10 ;)

Comment: Wouldn't it be even better to use wp_enqueue_style('style', get_stylesheet_uri());

Answer (score 1):

Do not use import.

Add time after css uri for refreshing everytime.

In your `function.php`

```
function child_style() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-child', get_stylesheet_uri().'?'.time());
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'child_style', 20 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Watch out from caching :

1. wp cache plug-ins
2. server side cache (APC etc.)
3. local browser cache